# SiteMaster site collection getting removed automatically from mysite content database

Tags: mysite

SiteMaster site collection is getting removed from mysite content database in SharePoint 2016 environment automatically when a new user with adfs identity initiate mysite creation.I have even restored old content dabatase of mysite but it again automatically delete sitemaster site collection when a new user initiate myste creation.Due to the reason of no sitemaster sitecollection, new users are failing to create their personal site.It is getting stucked forever in personal site setup.
Anyone has any idea of why sitemaster site collection is getting deleted automatically. I am totally unaware of the reason and not getting anwser any where else.

If anyone has faced the same issue and has a resolution,kindly assist me in resolving this issue.

btw, we have converted authentication provider from ntlm to adfs and since then this issue persist.Event log doesnot show up any solid clue.

Thanking you.